# Would it be unbalancing to have this kind of spiked warhammer in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, balance

The weapons I, as a GM, would like to include are warhammers (both a one and a two handed weapon) in the spike and flat, or often crenelated, style that real 14th century medieval hammers used, something that would be build a bit like this one:[image]

That stats would be as follows:

One-handed  12 gp   Dmg(S)1d6 Dmg(M)1d8 Crit x3 Weight 5lbs Type B or P
Two-handed  25 gp   Dmg(S)1d10 Dmg(M)1d12 Crit x3 Weight 10lbs Type B or P

The one-handed version to have a +1 bonus to Sunder Medium and Heavy Armour, and the two-handed version a +2.

Given the vast array of weapons that *are* part of the existing Pathfinder arsenal I'm concerned that there is something unbalancing about the proposed weapons that I'm missing that has prevented their inclusion. So my question is, hopefully, simple; would these weapons as proposed be unbalancing to the game?

Note I'm not married to the stats *exactly* as written if a minor tweak makes them more workable.

Comment: How's that any different from a regular warhammer (visually and flavor speaking, that is)?

Comment: @ShadowKras If I may, the traditional *fantasy* warhammer is an actual, for-reals, big ol' flat hammer (dealing only bludgeoning damage in *Pathfinder*, for example) instead of being like a real-life [warhammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_hammer) which the asker's weapon more closely resembles.

Comment: @ShadowKras Yeah what HeyICanChan said, Fantasy Warhammers, especially in Pathfinder owe more to the legend of [Mjölner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) than to practical weapons from the Medieval or Renascence era, they also top out as a one-handed weapon and I like the idea of a hammer that can be welded as a two-handed weapon, while I'm doing that I may as well get the "fantasy but closer to real world" flavour I want too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The balance for these weapons seem reasonable (except they should cost 23 gp and 40 gp if you want them to be martial weapons) w.r.t. custom weapon design rules.

You can find Pathfinder's weapon creation rules here: [Creating New Weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/#TOC-Creating-New-Weapons).  It comes from the *Weapon Master's Handbook*.  (GM approval still required of course.)

You can figure out the number of design points you have to work with based on if it is martial (5 DP) or exotic (6 DP).

All new weapons begin with the following base statistics: Dmg (M) 1d3; Critical ×2; Type any one (B, P, S); Price 1 gp × the weapon’s base DP.

#### 1-h, damage=1d8, critx3, B or P, sunder+1

- Improved Critical Multiplier (3 DP)
- Improved Damage (3 x 1 DP) - 3 steps to go from 1d3 to 1d8
- Additional Damage Type (1 DP)
- Weapon Feature (1 DP) - seems to fit for your sunder property (though technically not on the list)

These features would cost 8 DP.  A 1-handed martial weapon has a base of 7 DP (7 gp)and a 1-handed exotic weapon has a base of 8 DP (8 gp).

You can use Additional Design Points to get an extra DP for 15 gp more.  So **a martial version would cost 23 gp** and an exotic version would cost 8 gp.

#### 2-h, damage=1d12, critx3, B or P, sunder+2

- Improved Critical Multiplier (3 DP)
- Improved Damage (5 x 1 DP) - 5 steps to go from 1d3 to 1d12
- Additional Damage Type (1 DP)
- Weapon Feature (1 DP) - seems to fit for your sunder property (though technically not on the list)

These features would cost 10 DP.  A 2-handed martial weapon has a base of 8 DP (8 gp)and a 2-handed exotic weapon has a base of 9 DP (9 gp).

You can use Additional Design Points to get an extra DP for 15 gp more.  So **a martial version would cost 40 gp** and an exotic version would cost 25 gp.

Comment: I think the prices are 15 gp high in both cases; a one-handed martial weapon has a 7DP base allowance maxing at 9, Martial two-handed is 8DP base maxing at 11. The two-handed version compares closely with a Bec de Corbin but costs more and has less special abilities but one dice higher damage. I acknowledge you have a definite point about the one-handed version though.

Comment: Are you sure?  An exotic weapon has a base DP of 6, so would cost 30 gp.  Then you add in 30 gp from additional design points(x2).  For the 2-hander (if you can reduce the DP by 1) you add 45 gp from additional design points(x2) to get 75 gp.

Comment: Did you include the base DP increases that one- and two-handed weapons get over light weapons?

Comment: I did not, which changes everything.  I'll will fix that and that could bring your weapon back into good territory.

Comment: Wait a second the weapon costs 1x the total DP rating GP plus 15 additional GP for any additional DP slots purchased right? Shouldn't the one-handed version cost 8+15=23 GP and the two-handed version 10+30= 40 GP, both of those calculated as Martial Weapons?

Comment: Ha, I was multiplying the base DP by 5.  Not sure why.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at that book by the way, it's one I hadn't yet acquired and I can tell I'm going to have some fun with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78482/discussion-between-nick-brown-and-ash).

Answer (score 8):

### Take a Bec de Corbin as your base

A [Bec de Corbin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/bec-de-corbin/) is one of Pathfinder weapons that is influenced by real-world weapons and not stuck on fantasy, like the [warhammer](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/armsAndArmor/weapons.html#warhammer) (which is depicted on pathfinder art both [with spikes](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f9/dd/01/f9dd0146e3a54d05bf511dcbd8d694b9.jpg) and not, by the way).

[image]

It is a two-handed weapon, so it deals 1d10 damage rather than 1d8 from the warhammer, so you could merely scale it's size down to one-handed weapon and keep the **1d8 as base damage** for the weapon. The long handle turns it into a reach weapon, granting it both *reach* and *brace* (so it can be readied against a charge). The weapon already does either *bludgeoning* or *piercing* damage, which seems to be what you want.

Finally, you also keep the sunder property against armor, which is the [historical point](http://myarmoury.com/feature_spot_poleaxe.html) of that spike on the back.

> Benefit: You gain a +2 bonus to your CMB to **sunder** medium or heavy armor with a bec de corbin.

Comment: I did use this as a point of reference; can I remove the fact that it's a _reach_ and _brace_ weapon without causing problems? Making it a close quarters weapon as opposed to a polearm changes the flavour, as well as the restrictions on it's use, considerably. Thanks for pointing me at the concept art too, I hadn't seen that one before.

Comment: No. Reach has both advantages (to a higher degree) and disadvantages (to a lesser degree). So, removing reach will cause it to be a slightly weaker weapon, but will allow you to wield it one-handed.

Comment: Cool good to know I'm on the right track, if not quite there yet.

Comment: @NickBrown Yeah that's me, I'm designing for myself and my players and want to make sure that certain rules lawyers I know don't have too much to quibble over.